How to assign a group of buttons a function with onclick;
Am just trying to assign the same function to a bunch of buttons. I was having trouble referencing the buttons, I ran into "querySelectorAll is not a function" and same for getElementByClass, but with the current code it's referencing something because the function works, but only on load and not on click.
Here's the code:
let key;
let text;
let keys;

let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
for(let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
key = alphabet[i] + "Key";
text = document.createTextNode(alphabet[i].toUpperCase());
key = document.createElement("button");
key.appendChild(text);
key.classList.add("keys");
keyboard.append(key);
    }
keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys");
keys.onClick = isLetterThere();

}

function isLetterThere(){
console.log("fghjk")
}



Doing isLetterThere() invokes your isLetterThere function, setting the result of the call (undefined) to onClick. Rather you may have wanted (albeit in poor style) keys.onClick = isLetterThere, which would assign the function to onClick and allow it to be invoked via onClick(). This is still inferior to addEventListener, per the below answer.

In your code keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys"); this returns a collection. So you need to iterate this collection and add event to each of the element
You can do in two ways. Either you can add the addEventListener when you create the button.
Alternatively you can also add the event using querySelectorAll which will return a NodeList then loop of the collection and add event to it


let key;
let text;
let keys;
let keyboard = document.getElementById('keyboard')
let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function isLetterThere() {
  console.log("fghjk")
}

function testAlternative() {
  console.log("testAlternative")
}

for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
  key = alphabet[i] + "Key";
  text = document.createTextNode(alphabet[i].toUpperCase());
  key = document.createElement("button");
  key.appendChild(text);
  key.classList.add("keys");
  key.addEventListener('click', isLetterThere);
  keyboard.append(key);
}
document.querySelectorAll('.keys').forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', testAlternative));
<div id='keyboard'></div>






const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const keyboard = document.getElementById("keyboard"); // Assuming you have a div with id "keyboard" to append buttons to

alphabet.split("").forEach(letter => {
    const key = document.createElement("button");
    key.textContent = letter.toUpperCase();
    key.classList.add("keys");
    key.addEventListener("click", isLetterThere);
    keyboard.appendChild(key);
});

function isLetterThere() {
    console.log("fghjk");
}
<div id="keyboard"></div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Key's is an array-like-object, it does not have an onclick, nor an onClick, so assigning the result of isLetterThere() will execute the function once and assign its result to the array-like object, instead of your intention of creating a click handler for each letter-button. So, to achieve your goal, you will need to add click handlers to the elements, like key.addEventListener("click", isLetterThere)


let key;
let text;
let keys;
let keyboard = document.getElementById("keyboard");

let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
for(let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
    key = alphabet[i] + "Key";
    text = document.createTextNode(alphabet[i].toUpperCase());
    key = document.createElement("button");
    key.appendChild(text);
    key.classList.add("keys");
    keyboard.append(key);
    key.addEventListener("click", isLetterThere);
}
keys = document.querySelectorAll(".keys");
//keys.onClick = isLetterThere();


function isLetterThere(){
    console.log("fghjk")
}
<div id="keyboard"></div>



